# How to import openpyxl in snow park?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, openpyxl, snowpark

I see that opepyxl is supported in snow flake snowpark python https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/snowflake/ but every time I do import inside snowpark, I see the the below error:
Python Interpreter Error: Traceback (most recent call last): File "_udf_code.py", line 4, in  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'openpyxl' in function MYPROC with handler run

Not sure how to import. Can someone please share how I can use openpyxl in snowpark?

import openpyxl in snowpark and facing the below error:
Python Interpreter Error: Traceback (most recent call last): File "_udf_code.py", line 4, in  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'openpyxl' in function MYPROC with handler run

Comment: Please post the code that is producing this error, and the full stack trace of that error.

Comment: You should also format your tracebacks as code to make it easier to read.